# How to exit scrappy with status 1 running in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, scrapy, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to exit from scrapy with the status code 1 on exception. The script is running via DAG. But the task is not exiting with status code 1

```
try:
    photo = requests.get(self.img_url + '/' + inmate['ImageId']).content

except Exception as e:
       logging.error("Error is  " + str(e))
       self.spider.closespider_errorcount(1)
       raise CloseSpider(e)
       sys.exit(1)
```

> [2019-08-21 09:34:16,199] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -
>   scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider [2019-08-21 09:34:18,737]
>   {{bash_operator.py:131}} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
>   [2019-08-21 09:34:18,852] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job
>   26813: Subtask crawl_7001
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py:144:
>   UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release
>   2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see:
>   http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.
>   [2019-08-21 09:34:18,853] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job
>   26813: Subtask crawl_7001   """) [2019-08-21 09:34:21,189]
>   {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-08-21 09:34:21,189]
>   {{jobs.py:2630}} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally
>   set to success. Taking the poison pill. [2019-08-21 09:34:21,351]
>   {{helpers.py:281}} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 4765
>   [2019-08-21 09:34:21,436] {{helpers.py:263}} INFO - Process
>   psutil.Process(pid=4765, status='terminated') (4765) terminated with
>   exit code -15 [2019-08-21 09:34:21,437] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO -
>   [2019-08-21 09:34:21,437] {{jobs.py:2562}} INFO - Task exited with
>   return code 0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is the solution of mine:

The idea is to use `signals.spider_closed`

- quotes_spider.py

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, errback=self.parse_error)

    def parse(self, response):
        pass

    def parse_error(self, response):
        raise CloseSpider('My reason')
```

- crawl_process_wrapper.py

```py
import logging
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils import log
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class ScrapyCrawlerProcessWrapper:
    crawler_error = None
    crawler_closed = None

    def __init__(self, level_level: str = 'INFO'):

        self.crawler_error = None
        self.process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings(), False)
        log.dictConfig({
            'version': 1,
            'disable_existing_loggers': True,
            'loggers': {
                'scrapy': {
                    'level': level_level,
                }
            }
        })

    def add_spider(self, spider: scrapy.Spider, **know_args):
        logging.debug('add_spider: %s', spider)

        self.process.crawl(spider, **know_args)

    def start_crawl(self):

        for crawler in self.process.crawlers:
            crawler.signals.connect(receiver=self.spider_error, signal=signals.spider_error)
            crawler.signals.connect(receiver=self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

        # blocks the process till all crawlers finished
        self.process.start()

        # check for exceptions
        if self.crawler_error:
            self.crawler_error.raiseException()

        # check for exceptions
        if self.crawler_closed:
            logging.error('The crawler had been closed because: %s' % self.crawler_closed)
            exit(1)

    def spider_error(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'failure' in kwargs:
            print(kwargs['failure'])

            self.crawler_error = kwargs['failure']

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        if reason != 'finished':
            self.crawler_closed = reason
```